# Google Analytics: Cookie Duration set to 1 year

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In my current website, I am using Google Tag Manager to track certain events. I have embedded below script:

```
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=<googleTagmanagerId>"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>
    (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({
            'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
            event: 'gtm.js'
        });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j = d.createElement(s),
            dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src =
            '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', '<googleTagmanagerId>');
</script>
```

As part of this script, the cookie **_ga** is created with the duration of 2 years. As part of buisness request I have to set it as 1 year.

Is it possible to set the cookie duration of **__ga** in the above code snippet?

Also can I set the cookie duration of **__ga** from Google Tag Manager Account dashboard.

I also tried below code:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {
  'cookieName': 'gaCookie',
  'cookieDomain': 'blog.example.co.uk',
  'cookieExpires': 60 * 60 * 24 * 28  // Time in seconds.
});
```

The above snippet works but creates a duplicate _ga cookie :(

Answer (score 3):

The tag manager snippet is only loading the tag manager with a specific container. If you want to change tracking tags configured in the container, then you need to login to your gtm account, change tags and then publish the new version of the container.

Configuring the cookie expiration field on a UA tracking tag, should look like this:

[image: UA tag fields]

Ideally, you would use the "Google Analytics Settings" field so you can make later updates/additions without needing to modify all GA tags individually.

If you instead try to modify the default cookie's expiration like so:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {
// No cookie name to get the default name
// cookieDomain only needed if it is different than the auto-calculated.
  'cookieExpires': 60 * 60 * 24 * 28  // Time in seconds.
});
```

The cookie will be modified, but you are not modifying all of your tracking tags so the next event or page view is going to set the time to 2 years from when it tracks.